# Combine (or replace) indexing with dplyr filtering (to plot raster)

Tags: r, dplyr, r-raster, magrittr

I have a `data.frame`/`tibble` with once variable that is a list of raster bricks, e.g, `a`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(raster)

x <- matrix(
  data = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  nrow = 10,
  ncol = 10
) %>%
  raster

y <- matrix(
  data = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  nrow = 10,
  ncol = 10
) %>%
  raster

z <- matrix(
  data = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
  nrow = 10,
  ncol = 10
) %>%
  raster

a <- tribble(
  ~thing, ~map,
  "b", brick(x, y),
  "c", brick(z, y),
  "d", brick(x, z),
  "e", brick(y, z),
)

a
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   thing map       
#>   <chr> <list>    
#> 1 b     <RstrBrck>
#> 2 c     <RstrBrck>
#> 3 d     <RstrBrck>
#> 4 e     <RstrBrck>
```

I want to pull out some rasters from within the bricks to plot, e.g.:

```r
plot(a$map[[3]][[2]])
```

[image]

But rather than index to the row, I want to use `dplyr::filter` to select the appropriate row to plot, and I can get to the appropriate column using `pull` but I can't get my head around how to get then to the appropriate raster within the brick object in order to plot it, short of assigning it as a new object and then indexing the new object. What I want to do is something like the below (which fails):

```r
a %>%
  filter(thing == "d") %>%
  pull(map)[[2]] %>%
  plot
#> Error in pull(map): object 'map' not found
```

Solutions?

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
a %>%
  filter(thing == "d") %>%
  pull(map) %>%
  .[[1]] %>% 
  .[[2]] %>% 
  plot

a %>%
  filter(thing == "d") %>%
  .$map %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  .[[2]] %>% 
  plot
```

Note that `pull(map)` is equivalent to `.$map`.

Comment: Thanks - I guess the point here is that this is `magrittr` behaviour we need to deal with, not inherent `dplyr` behaviour - I always forget that now that piping is integrated into `dplyr`.